# snakemake - define input for aggregate rule without wildcards

Tags: snakemake

I am writing a snakemake to produce Sars-Cov-2 variants from Nanopore sequencing. The pipeline that I am writing is based on the [artic network](https://artic.network/), so I am using `artic guppyplex` and `artic minion`.

The snakemake that I wrote has the following steps:

1. zip all the `fastq` files for all barcodes (rule `zipFq`)
2. perform read filtering with `guppyplex` (rule `guppyplex`)
3. call the `artic minion` pipeline (rule `minion`)
4. move the stderr and stdout from qsub to a folder under the working directory (rule `mvQsubLogs`)

Below is the snakemake that I wrote so far, which works

```
barcodes = ['barcode49', 'barcode50', 'barcode51']

rule all:
    input:
        expand([
            # zip fq
            "zipFastq/{barcode}/{barcode}.zip",

            # guppyplex
            "guppyplex/{barcode}/{barcode}.fastq",

            # nanopolish
            "nanopolish/{barcode}",

            # directory where the logs will be moved to    
            "logs/{barcode}"
        ], barcode = barcodes)

rule zipFq:
    input: 
        FQ = f"{FASTQ_PATH}/{{barcode}}"
    output:
        "zipFastq/{barcode}/{barcode}.zip"
    shell:
        "zip {output} {input.FQ}/*"


rule guppyplex:
    input:
        FQ = f"{FASTQ_PATH}/{{barcode}}" # FASTQ_PATH is parsed from config.yaml
    output:
        "guppyplex/{barcode}/{barcode}.fastq"
    shell:
        "/home/ngs/miniconda3/envs/artic-ncov2019/bin/artic guppyplex --skip-quality-check --min-length {MINLENGTHGUPPY} --max-length {MAXLENGTHGUPPY} --directory {input.FQ} --prefix {wildcards.barcode} --output {output}" # variables in CAPITALS are parsed from config.yaml


rule minion:
    input:
        INFQ = rules.guppyplex.output,
        FAST5 = f"{FAST5_PATH}/{{barcode}}"
    params:
        OUTDIR = "nanopolish/{barcode}"
    output:
        directory("nanopolish/{barcode}")
    shell:
        """
        mkdir {params.OUTDIR};
        cd {params.OUTDIR};
        export PATH=/home/ngs/miniconda3/envs/artic-ncov2019/bin:$PATH;
        artic minion --normalise {NANOPOLISH_NORMALISE} --threads {THREADS} --scheme-directory {PRIMERSDIR} --read-file ../../{input.INFQ} --sequencing-summary {Seq_Sum} --fast5-directory {input.FAST5}  nCoV-2019/{PRIMERVERSION} {wildcards.barcode} # variables in CAPITALS are parsed from config.yaml
        """

rule mvQsubLogs:
    input:
        # zipFQ
        rules.zipFq.output,

        # guppyplex
        rules.guppyplex.output,

        # nanopolish
        rules.minion.output
    output:
        directory("logs/{barcode}")
    shell:
        "mkdir -p {output} \n"
        "mv {LOGDIR}/{wildcards.barcode}* {output}/"
```

The above snakemake works and now I am trying to add another rule, but the difference here is that this rule is an aggregate function i.e. it should not be called for every `barcode`, but only once after all the rules are called for all barcodes

The rule that I am trying to incorporate (catFasta) would `cat` all `{barcode}.consensus.fasta` (generated by rule `minion`) into in a single file, as shown below (incorporated into the snakemake above):

```
barcodes = ['barcode49', 'barcode50', 'barcode51']

rule all:
    input:
        expand([
            # zip fq
            "zipFastq/{barcode}/{barcode}.zip",

            # guppyplex
            "guppyplex/{barcode}/{barcode}.fastq",

            # nanopolish
            "nanopolish/{barcode}",
            
            # catFasta
            "catFasta/cat_consensus.fasta",

            # directory where the logs will be moved to    
            "logs/{barcode}"
        ], barcode = barcodes)

rule zipFq:
    input: 
        FQ = f"{FASTQ_PATH}/{{barcode}}"
    output:
        "zipFastq/{barcode}/{barcode}.zip"
    shell:
        "zip {output} {input.FQ}/*"


rule guppyplex:
    input:
        FQ = f"{FASTQ_PATH}/{{barcode}}" # FASTQ_PATH is parsed from config.yaml
    output:
        "guppyplex/{barcode}/{barcode}.fastq"
    shell:
        "/home/ngs/miniconda3/envs/artic-ncov2019/bin/artic guppyplex --skip-quality-check --min-length {MINLENGTHGUPPY} --max-length {MAXLENGTHGUPPY} --directory {input.FQ} --prefix {wildcards.barcode} --output {output}" # variables in CAPITALS are parsed from config.yaml


rule minion:
    input:
        INFQ = rules.guppyplex.output,
        FAST5 = f"{FAST5_PATH}/{{barcode}}"
    params:
        OUTDIR = "nanopolish/{barcode}"
    output:
        directory("nanopolish/{barcode}")
    shell:
        """
        mkdir {params.OUTDIR};
        cd {params.OUTDIR};
        export PATH=/home/ngs/miniconda3/envs/artic-ncov2019/bin:$PATH;
        artic minion --normalise {NANOPOLISH_NORMALISE} --threads {THREADS} --scheme-directory {PRIMERSDIR} --read-file ../../{input.INFQ} --sequencing-summary {Seq_Sum} --fast5-directory {input.FAST5}  nCoV-2019/{PRIMERVERSION} {wildcards.barcode} # variables in CAPITALS are parsed from config.yaml
        """

rule catFasta:
    input:
        expand("nanopolish/{barcode}/{barcode}.consensus.fasta", barcode = barcodes)
    output:
        "catFasta/cat_consensus.fasta"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"

rule mvQsubLogs:
    input:
        # zipFQ
        rules.zipFq.output,

        # guppyplex
        rules.guppyplex.output,

        # nanopolish
        rules.minion.output,

        # catFasta
        rules.catFasta.output
    output:
        directory("logs/{barcode}")
    shell:
        "mkdir -p {output} \n"
        "mv {LOGDIR}/{wildcards.barcode}* {output}/"
```

However, when I call snakemake with

```
(artic-ncov2019) ngs@bngs05b:/nexusb/SC2/ONT/scripts/SnakeMake> snakemake -np -s Snakefile_v2 --cluster "qsub -q onlybngs05b -e {LOGDIR} -o {LOGDIR} -j y" -j 5 --jobname "{wildcards.barcode}.{rule}.{jobid}" all # LOGDIR parsed from config.yaml
```

I get:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 178 of /nexusb/SC2/ONT/scripts/SnakeMake/Snakefile_v2:
Missing input files for rule guppyplex:
/nexus/Gridion/20210521_Covid7/Covid7/20210521_0926_X1_FAL11796_a5b62ac2/fastq_pass/barcode49/barcode49.consensus.fasta
```

Which I don't find easy to understand: snakemake is complaining about `/nexus/Gridion/20210521_Covid7/Covid7/20210521_0926_X1_FAL11796_a5b62ac2/fastq_pass/barcode49/barcode49.consensus.fasta` whereas `/nexus/Gridion/20210521_Covid7/Covid7/20210521_0926_X1_FAL11796_a5b62ac2/fastq_pass/` is `FASTQ_PATH` and I am not defining `f"{FASTQ_PATH}/{{barcode}}.consensus.fasta"` anywhere

A very same problem is described [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/6804/wildcards-object-has-no-attribute-sample), though the strategy in the accepted answer (the input for rule `catFasta` would be `expand("nanopolish/{{barcode}}/{{barcode}}.consensus.fasta")`) does not work for me.

Does anyone know how I can circumvent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule that fails is `rule guppyplex`, which looks for an input in the form of `{FASTQ_PATH}/{{barcode}}`.

Looks like the wildcard `{barcode}` is filled with `barcode49/barcode49.consensus.fasta`, which happened because of two reasons I think:

First (and most important): The workflow does not find a better way to produce the final output. In `rule catFasta`, you give an input file which is never described as an output in your workflow. The `rule minion` has the directory as an output, but not the file, and it is not perfectly clear for the workflow where to produce this input file.

It therefore infers that the `{barcode}` wildcard somehow has to contain this `.consensus.fasta` that it has never seen before. This wildcard is then handed over to the top, where the workflow crashes since it cannot find a matching input file.

Second: This initialisation of the wildcard with sth. you don't want is only possible since you did not constrain the wildcard properly. You can for example forbid the wildcard to contain a `.` (see `wildcard_constraints` [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#wildcards))

However, the main problem is that `catFasta` does not find the desired input. I'd suggest changing the output of `minion` to `"nanopolish/{barcode}/{barcode}.consensus.fasta"`, since the you already take the OUTDIR from the params, that should not hurt your rule here.

Edit: Dummy test example:

```
barcodes = ['barcode49', 'barcode50', 'barcode51']

rule all:
    input:
        expand([
            # guppyplex
            "guppyplex/{barcode}/{barcode}.fastq",

            # catFasta
            "catFasta/cat_consensus.fasta",
        ], barcode = barcodes)


rule guppyplex:
    input:
        FQ = f"fastq/{{barcode}}" # FASTQ_PATH is parsed from config.yaml
    output:
        "guppyplex/{barcode}/{barcode}.fastq"
    shell:
        "touch {output}" # variables in CAPITALS are parsed from config.yaml


rule minion:
    input:
        INFQ = rules.guppyplex.output,
        FAST5 = f"fasta/{{barcode}}"
    params:
        OUTDIR = "nanopolish/{barcode}"
    output:
        "nanopolish/{barcode}/{barcode}.consensus.fasta"
    shell:
        """
        touch {output} && echo {wildcards.barcode} > {output}
        """

rule catFasta:
    input:
        expand("nanopolish/{barcode}/{barcode}.consensus.fasta", barcode = barcodes)
    output:
        "catFasta/cat_consensus.fasta"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have changed the output of `minion` rule (`output: "nanopolish/{barcode}/{barcode}.consensus.fasta"`, same for `rule all`) and I am getting the same error `AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'barcode'`. I get no error after a dry run, I get the exact command that I need printed, though it shows no wildcard

Comment: I've just seen that you write `barcode = barcodes` in the `expand()`, but I don't see this `barcodes` list. I think you named it  `samples`.

Comment: yes, sorry for the typo in fact I want the snakemake to iterate over a simple python list called `barcodes`

Comment: And the wildcard does not fill even though the `barcodes` list exists in your running version?
Could you post the messages of the dry run and the failing error message?

Comment: The command that I get from the dry run is `cat nanopolish/barcode94/barcode94.consensus.fasta nanopolish/barcode95/barcode95.consensus.fasta nanopolish/barcode96/barcode96.consensus.fasta > catFasta/cat_consensus.fasta`, which is the exact command that I need. Error message is `AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'barcode'`

Comment: Hmm, I made a quick minimal test with `guppyplex`,`minion` and `catFasta` where I just create dummy output  with `touch` and that runs fine for me.
And the wildcard-field is empty during the dry-run? Then, I really wonder where `catFasta` pulls those `barcode95` etc. from.

Comment: perhaps you can share your code with your answer so that I can have a look at what you have done differently?

Comment: thanks for the answer, in fact the error that I was getting is not inside the Snakefile, but actually in how I was calling it: `snakemake -p -s Snakefile_v2 --cluster "qsub -q onlybngs05b -e {LOGDIR} -o {LOGDIR} -j y" -j 5 --jobname "{wildcards.barcode}.{rule}.{jobid}" all` (the value that I pass to `--jobname` - without it, it works). It appears I need to create a cluster config file, where I would define `wildcards`, are you familiar with that?

Comment: in case you want to have a closer look at the problem I am having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67906871/snakemake-replacing-command-line-parameters-with-wildcards-by-cluster-profile