# snakemake - replacing command line parameters with wildcards by cluster profile

Tags: snakemake

I am writing a snakemake pipeline to eventually identify corona virus variants.

Below is a minimal example with three steps:

```
LOGDIR = '/path/to/logDir'
barcodes = ['barcode49', 'barcode50', 'barcode51']

rule all:
    input:
        expand([
            # guppyplex
            "out/guppyplex/{barcode}/{barcode}.fastq",

            # catFasta
            "out/catFasta/cat_consensus.fasta",
        ], barcode = barcodes)


rule guppyplex:
    input:
        FQ = f"fastq/{{barcode}}" # FASTQ_PATH is parsed from config.yaml
    output:
        "out/guppyplex/{barcode}/{barcode}.fastq"
    shell:
        "touch {output}" # variables in CAPITALS are parsed from config.yaml


rule minion:
    input:
        INFQ = rules.guppyplex.output,
        FAST5 = f"fasta/{{barcode}}"
    params:
        OUTDIR = "out/nanopolish/{barcode}"
    output:
        "out/nanopolish/{barcode}/{barcode}.consensus.fasta"
    shell:
        """
        touch {output} && echo {wildcards.barcode} > {output}
        """

rule catFasta:
    input:
        expand("out/nanopolish/{barcode}/{barcode}.consensus.fasta", barcode = barcodes)
    output:
        "out/catFasta/cat_consensus.fasta"
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"
```

If I run the snakemake locally by calling `snakemake -p --cores 1 all` everything works. Yet my ultimate goal is to use `qsub` to run the jobs on a cluster. I also want the stderr and stdout from qsub to have meaningful names, which include wildcards and the rule names for each job.

However, if I call snakemake with

```
snakemake -p --cluster "qsub -q onlybngs05b -e {LOGDIR} -o {LOGDIR} -j y" -j 5 --jobname "{wildcards.barcode}.{rule}.{jobid}" all
```

I will get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Wildcards' object has no attribute 'barcode'
```

I have recently read the [snakemake documentation](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cli.html#profiles) where it appears that I could replace the command line parameters (`--cluster "qsub -q onlybngs05b -e {LOGDIR} -o {LOGDIR} -j y" -j 5 --jobname "{wildcards.barcode}.{rule}.{jobid}"`) by a yaml file. Although the documentation is not all that clear to me.

I have created a `config.yaml` file at `/home/user/.config/snakemake` which looks like so:

```
cluster: 'qsub'
q: 'onlybngs05b'
e: '/home/ngs/tempOutSnakemake'
o: '/home/ngs/tempOutSnakemake'
j: 5
jobname: "{wildcards.barcode}.{rule}.{jobid}
```

But then it appears that snakemake is not properly parsing the `config.yaml`. I am getting

```
snakemake: error: ambiguous option: --o=/home/ngs/tempOutSnakemake could match --omit-from, --output-wait, --overwrite-shellcmd
```

I also tried to replace `o` in the config file by  `stdout` (kind of the long version of the parameter (`-h` vs `--help` for several programs), though it does not work.

Therefore my question is how I can replace the command line parameters `--cluster "qsub -q onlybngs05b -e {LOGDIR} -o {LOGDIR} -j y" -j 5 --jobname "{wildcards.barcode}.{rule}.{jobid}"` by a `config.yaml` file that accepts wildcards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that rule `catFasta` doesn't contain the wildcard `barcode`. If you think about it, what job name would you expect in `{wildcards.barcode}.{rule}.{jobid}`?

Maybe a solution could be to add to each rule a `jobname` parameter that could  be `{barcode}` for `guppyplex` and `minion` and `'all_barcodes'` for `catFasta`. Then use `--jobname "{params.jobname}.{rule}.{jobid}"`

Comment: makes sense that there would be no precise name for rule carFasta, was not looking from that perspective, though it is exactly what I needed, thanks very much